# Mule Flow only for Integration Testing

Tags: mule

I have got the Mule 4 application which is driven by Scheduler to schedule every 30 minutes. I have added http listener under the file test-listener.xml just for invoking it for building the integration testing.

I want the test-listener.xml to be deployed only into non-production environment. How can I achieve it in Mule 4.3.0 Runtime

Thanks

Comment: Mule flows can be enabled/disabled through the property 
<flow name="example" inialState="false">. You could use a property to enable/disable that flow base on environment.

Although I can see your intention, I strongly believe that this approach is completely wrong:
A) you are including unnecessary code
B) you are introducing an HTTP listener that by human mistake, may get open in production.
C) you are not properly testing your application, as you are bypassing the scheduler behavour.

Comment: Use the Cloudhub API endpoint to trigger the scheduler externally: 
 https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/minor/1.0/console/method/%233255/

Comment: As @mariomartinez said, this is a wrong approach.

Comment: @mariomartinez. Thanks for the detailed response. Completely agreed with whatever you said. We are not using cloud anypoint platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an HTTP Listener to test the flow is not a good practice. If you are interested on just testing the flow just use MUnit to implement tests of the flow. If you are interested on testing the scheduler execution you can use this method with MUnit: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/test-flow-with-scheduler-cookbook